# Update state after x amount of seconds on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, setinterval

I am trying to get a state changed every (let's say) 2 or 3 seconds, I am using setInterval for that, but I notice it only changes the first time and then it overrides the state to its original value , which is an array of 3 empty objects,

What I want to accomplish is the objects to change to something
like: `state = [{id:3, letter: B, status: false}, {}, {} ]` on first run for example , then on second run (after a few seconds), it needs to keep previos state `arr[0]` to move it to `arr[1]` and the new `arr[0]` will be a new random object I get so on second run it will change to something like `state = [{id:56, letter: G, status: false},{id:3, letter: B, status: false}, {} ]`

All this should be accomplished on a click of a button.

I am putting some of my code below and I hope this makes sense

```
import React from 'react';

const getLetter = (number) => {
    if (number >= 0 && number < 15) {
      return "B";
    } else if (number >= 15 && number < 30) {
      return "I";
    } else if (number >= 30 && number < 45) {
      return "N";
    } else if (number >= 45 && number < 60) {
      return "G";
    } else if (number >= 60 && number < 75) {
      return "O";
    }
  };

const pending = function (arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
};

const Bingo = () => {

const [balls, setBalls] = useState(
        Array.from(Array(75)).map((_, index) => {
          return { id: index + 1, letter: getLetter(index), status: false };
        })
      );
        //this is the state I want to update to be displayed , the state contains 3 objects with data I want to display on screen 
const [lastBalls, setLastBalls] = useState([{},{},{}])

    const [intervalID, setIntervalID] = useState(null);

    const random = () => {

      const newGame = pending(
        balls.filter((ball) => balls.status === false)
      );
      if (newGame) {
          let prevState = [...lastBalls];
            prevState[2] = prevState[1]
            prevState[1] = prevState[0]
            prevState[0] = newGame;
            setLastBalls(prevState);
      }
    };

    const automatedGame = () => {
      if(intervalID === null){
        setIntervalID(setInterval(random, 1000 //this number may change to 2000 or 5000 for example));
      }
    }

const pause = () => {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      setIntervalID(null);
    }
 return ( 
        <>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table balls={balls} />
              <Button onClick={automatedGame}>Play (Auto)</Button>
              <Boton onClick={pause}>Pause</Boton>
              <PlayedBalls balls={lastBalls}/>
        </TableContainer>
        </>
     );
}
```

Currently, if I run this ode when I click the button 'Play (Auto)' it does run and executes the function, but the state keeps being changed to modify the first element of the lastBalls state only so it only updates the first object but never passes the other two to position 1 and 2, why would this be happening?